# Calling no-params webservice operation from Camel route using CXF

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

`ThingsService` is a webservice interface generated by jax-ws (stripped of annotations for the sake of brevity). There is one parameter-less method:

```
public interface ThingsService {
    AvailableThingsResponse getAvailableThings();
}
```

Trying to call the no-parameters operation from a Camel route using CXF like this:

```
from("timer:start?fixedRate=true")
        .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, constant("getAvailableThings")
        .to("cxf:http://localhost:8080/services/things"
            + "?serviceClass=" + ThingsService.class.getName());
```

causes Camel to barf when calling the endpoint:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Get the wrong
>   parameter size to invoke the out service, Expect size 0, Parameter
>   size 1. Please check if the message body matches the CXFEndpoint POJO
>   Dataformat request.
>   at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.checkParameterSize(CxfProducer.java:283)
>   at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.getParams(CxfProducer.java:321)
>   at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:131)
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
>   at  org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
>   at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:192)
>   at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:76)
>   at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
>   at util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

The CXF endpoint is in POJO mode, exchange body being sent to the endpoint is null.

**What's the proper way of calling a no-params WS operation from Camel route using CXF component?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that no-params is represented using an empty array:

```
from("timer:start?fixedRate=true")
        .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, constant("getAvailableThings")
        .transform().body(o -> new Object[0])
        .to("cxf:http://localhost:8080/services/things"
            + "?serviceClass=" + ThingsService.class.getName());
```

Comment: I logged a ticket to make this easier: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10607.

Comment: What version of Apache Camel are you using?

Comment: @ClausIbsen The most recent, 2.18.1.